# shared link already exists - Dropbox API v2

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropbox, dropbox-api

Im creating the following process:

1. Upload a file to dropbox using the API
2. After upload, create a shared link for that file
3. If a shared link already exists, get that existing shared link for the user

**My Issue:**

Im using the following code to check if the shared link already exists:

```
if(x.error[".tag"] === "shared_link_already_exists"){
  //code to get existing shared link here
}
```

**When I upload a new file which has never had a shared link created I get the following error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '.tag' of undefined
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: why don't you check whether error exists and then  `.tag` inside as follows  `!!x.error && x.error[".tag"] === "shared_link_already_exists"] `

Answer (score 2):

If you get the `shared_link_already_exists` error when calling [/2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-create_shared_link_with_settings), you can retrieve the existing link by calling [/2/sharing/list_shared_links](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_shared_links) with `path` set to the path of the file/folder for which you want a link, and `direct_only=true`.

And kgangadhar's comment is correct, you should check if there is an error before attempting to access `'.tag'` on it.